# How to find the longest sequence in a 2d array?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a 2d grid, with the below constraints, I want to find the longest sub-sequence :

1. allowed to move up, right, left, down, diagonally
2. difference between the current value and the next value should be greater than or equal to 3 (i.e absolute difference).
3. visited cells should not be repeated
4. grid could be maximum 10 x 10
5. not allowed to do 4 -> 9 in the below example

Example:

```
824
061
379
```

The length of the longest path for the above input is 8, with the sequence 9,1,6,2,8,0,7,3

I tired to approach using multiple for loops, but it would be highly inefficient. I want to know how do I approach using Dynamic Programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you want to use dynamic programming you need to define a recurrence relation with base case first. that shouldn't be very hard since you already got a feeling that the same subproblems are called multiple times

Comment: Pham, I've edited the question. It's actually greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: This looks like a variation of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem to me. So there might be no efficient solution.

Comment: Why not do a depth first search instead of dynamic programming?

Comment: apparently I think it cannot be solved by means of dynamic programming, because all subproblems are distinct from each other. for example, we would like to find sequences starting with `2` and `7`. at first glance it seems that going one step down for `2` and one step up for `7` will call the same subproblem i.e. `start with 6`, but it is actually not the same subproblem because if we go from `2`, then `2` is visited so we can't pick `2` anymore, and if we go from `7` then `7` is visited and we can't pick `7` anymore

Comment: @vivek_23 depth-first search is not going to help here, i think SaiBot is correct, it's a variation of longest path problem

Comment: @mangusta why it won't help?

Comment: @vivek_23 because there is no guarantee that DFS will follow the longest path of the graph

Comment: @mangusta Not sure. Can you give an example so that I can understand better?

Comment: @vivek_23 I described two different scenarios for DFS of the graph in the question, starting from `9`: https://ibb.co/eMdpkV  . as you see, left one indeed shows the longest path of the graph, while the right one does not. you never know whether DFS will traverse along the longest path or not

Comment: by the way it is worthwhile to note that if graph has no cycles then the longest path can indeed be found by doing DFS, so the graph could be checked for the presence of cycles first and if no cycles were found, DFS would do the job

Comment: @mangusta DFS will not produce the longest path on every run but it will surely get the longest path right at least once, like the traversal on the left hand side of the image you showed. So, DFS would always give the correct solution(yes let's say graph has no cycles). However, this problem is tricky since it includes diagonal moments too. It is timing out in the solution I devised

Comment: @Ramesh With dynamic programming, you can memoize a solution for each index but when you calculate it for other indexes, you can't be sure if the subproblem went through the host index for their longest paths or not.

Comment: What does "not allowed to do 4 -> 9 in the below example" mean? 4 -> 1 is allowed, right?

Comment: @vivek_23 I've added an answer which gets me the length for the longest increasing sub sequence. Can you suggest, how do I accomodate the condition to make sure the next element in the array is greater than 3? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ramesh 1) You can't post an answer which is an extension of your question. Edit your question and add your code there.`Answers` are meant to `answer` the question. 2) The code you have differs a lot from your goal.For your goal, you will have to have a `visited` bool array not visit the same cell again, else it would lead to StackOverflow error.Let's say you cache an answer for a cell. Later on,when you visit the same cell from a different cell via DFS, you can't guarantee whether the `return cache[i][j]`  will never have the host cell through which the call was made to the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

Just run [bfs (Breadth-first search)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from every possible source in the grid by following the constraints. For example, in your given sample input the number of possible source is 9. Then, save the paths in some suitable data structure. After saving the paths, check which path is longest and that's your answer.